# Append MongoDb ObjectId to the python Class Object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I would like to append the `result1` variable to the class object `Transaction` in python. I tried json_util but didn't work.

```
import json
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
from bson import json_util
from pymongo import MongoClient

class Medicine:
    def __init__(self, sku, name, diagnosis):
        self.sku = sku        
        self.name = name        
        self.diagnosis = diagnosis    
        
    def jsonable(self):
        return self.__dict__

class Transaction:
    def __init__(self, custId, bill_no, parent_tx_id, med):
        self.custId = custId        
        self.bill_no = bill_no        
        self.parent_txxxx_id = parent_tx_id        
        self.med = med    
    
    def jsonable(self):
        return self.__dict__

class Diagnosis:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name    

    def jsonable(self):
        return self.__dict__
        
def ComplexHandler(Obj):
    if hasattr(Obj, 'jsonable'):
        return Obj.jsonable()
    else:
        raise TypeError

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://root:xyz@abcmongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
# Select the database and collection
db = client["test"]
collection = db["collection1"]

# Run the query and extract the _id values from the documents
result1 = [doc["_id"] for doc in collection.find({}, {"_id": 1})]

# Print the results
print(result1) #Sample Output: [ObjectId('6409b51df917b0440431c0ba'), ObjectId('6409b51df917b0440431c0bb')]
    
diag = Diagnosis("CBT")
med = Medicine("SKU01", "Dolo", diag)
transaction = Transaction("adsf", "bu_bill", result1, med)
jsonTran = json.dumps(transaction, default=ComplexHandler)
print(jsonTran)
```

Expected Output :

```
{"custId": "adsf", "bill_no": "123", "parent_txxxx_id": [ObjectId('6409b51df917b0440431c0ba'), ObjectId('6409b51df917b0440431c0bb')], "med": {"sku": "SKU01", "name": "Dolo", "diagnosis": {"name": "CBT"}}}
```

Error is

```
File "x.py", line 55, in <module>
 jsonTran = json.dumps(transaction, default=ComplexHandler)  
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps     
 return cls(   
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode   
  chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)   
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode             
  return _iterencode(o, 0)   
File "x.py", line 39, in ComplexHandler
 raise TypeError TypeError
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: ```File "x.py", line 55, in <module>
    jsonTran = json.dumps(transaction, default=ComplexHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "x.py", line 39, in ComplexHandler
    raise TypeError
TypeError ``` @BellyBuster

Answer (score 1):

`json.dumps()` can only serialise objects [it understands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#py-to-json-table) into JSON.

You are passing it an `ObjectId` object which is not handled by your default encoder.

Either get rid of the `ObjectId`s, e.g. by changing this line to:

```
result1 = [str(doc["_id"]) for doc in collection.find({}, {"_id": 1})]
```

Or add the logic to your encoder, e.g.

```
class ComplexHandler(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'jsonable'):
            return obj.jsonable()
        if hasattr(obj, '__str__'):  # This will handle ObjectIds
            return str(obj)

        return super(ComplexHandler, self).default(obj)
```

and then use:

```
jsonTran = json.dumps(transaction, cls=ComplexHandler)
```